# About partitions, majorization, and conjugates

Tags: combinatorics

I am trying to solve a question of a property of conjugation.
What I am trying to show is that conjugation reverses the order of majorization.

Let $\lambda$ and $\mu$ are partitions of n and $\lambda$ is majorized by $\mu$.

$\lambda:n=\lambda_1+\lambda_2+\lambda_3+ \cdots + \lambda_k$

$\mu:n=\mu_1+\mu_2+\mu_3+ \cdots + \mu_k$

'$\lambda$ is majorized by $\mu$' means that
$\lambda_1+\lambda_2+\lambda_3+ \cdots + \lambda_i \leq \mu_1+\mu_2+\mu_3+ \cdots + \mu_i$ for $i=1,2,\cdots,k$

Then, showing that $\mu^*\leq\lambda^*$ would be enough to say that conjugation reverses the order of majorization.

But, I am stuck from the beginning after writing the definitions of majorization and conjugation.

Please help me. Thanks

Comment: What does it mean to say that one partition of $n$ majorizes another partition of $n$?

Comment: Sorry. I just added what a partition majorizes another partition means.